# laravel eloquent with multiple where conditions issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my laravel based application's database, I have a table to store records of the user payments.

I'm having created_at column to store the record creation date and payment_annum column to store the subscription type(monthly or yearly)

Now I'm trying to display those records on my admin dashboard blade. But the thing is i only need to display the last month's, MONTHLY subscription records only.

So far I could retrieve data where the subscription type is monthly but struggling to filter it by the last month..

This is my current eloquent, where only checks the subscription type

```
$get_monthly_payments_lastmonth=AppPayment::where('payment_annum','=','monthly')
        ->get();
```

So how can I check the 'last month' condition as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your eloquent to this,

```
$get_monthly_payments_lastmonth=AppPayment::where('payment_annum','=','monthly')
        ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->month)
        ->get();
```

this would give give you the last month records where the payment_annum is monthly

Comment: you might get issues with this later. This will return month as an integer and you will get records for a month regardless of the year.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your query to return all elements created in the last month (as of today: `created_by` matching `2020-03-*`) or rather created *during* the last month (`created_by >= 2020-03-23`)?

For March, extend the accepted solution by

```
$get_monthly_payments_lastmonth=AppPayment::where('payment_annum','=','monthly')
        ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->month)
        ->whereYear('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->year)
        ->get();
```

For the latter, this should do:

```
$get_monthly_payments_lastmonth=AppPayment::where('payment_annum','=','monthly')
        ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMonth())
        ->get();
```